# Next.js - are .env called in a page visible frontend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, security, next.js

I'm trying to secure my API routes, so I have a token in my .env list, my doubt is, is it visible frontend if I call it like so?

```
const siteUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SITE_URL
const key = process.env.MY_TOKEN

export default function Page(){

   ...

   fetch(`${siteUrl}/api/xxx/${query}?t=${key}`);

   ...

}
```

cause for instance `siteUrl` uses the `NEXT_PUBLIC_SITE_URL` which I recall reading it was publicly visible (hence the name "PUBLIC"), but when I tried to search via chrome Elements and Sources there's no trace of either `siteUrl` or `key`

**EDIT:** well I just noticed that I was testing the live version (that's why no error was thrown), on my localhost is in fact throwing error because it refuses to read that `key` .env . So I guess the question now becomes: should I prepend "NEXT_PUBLIC" to the .env variable? does that make it visible frontend? or should I go straight with something like:

```
const siteUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SITE_URL
const key = 'mystringtoken'

export default function Page(){

   ...

   fetch(`${siteUrl}/api/xxx/${query}?t=${key}`);

   ...

}
```

Comment: Anything that you use in the frontend will be visible to the client. To make this behavior clear, NextJS expects all the env variables to have a prefix "NEXT_PUBLIC" which are being consumed in the frontend. If these environment variables contains some secret, the best way would be to call them in the backend (inside /pages/api/* or useServerSideProps ,getStaticProps etc)

Comment: the props generated inside useServerSideProps ,getStaticProps are for data that needs to be generated once, and the prop is passed to the DOM anyway as soon as you retrieve it inside the Page({ myprop }){ ... } . My case is like an API route that fires up at every input search the user does, inside that api js file I call a external API service to retrieve the data, so is there no way to protect that basically? by "protect" I mean only the app can fires that up, if a user types the same /api/myapi.js path manually in the browser it should throw error

Comment: well the external API inside my /api/file.js is not a good example as you may say ok then load the process.env.KEY inside the api route and use it as key in the external api call instead of writing it as a string, and that's something I already do where the external API asks for an API key, but what for those which don't ask one, or for a database call instead? can't be "protected" by a .env token so that it works only if fired up within the app?